# Why does the sample mean of a Poisson distribution have minimum variance over all unbiased estimators?

Tags: statistics, estimation

Suppose $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean of i.i.d Poisson random variables with mean parameter $\lambda$, and $T$ is any other unbiased estimator. How do we prove without any theorem in Statistics that $E\left(\bar{X}-\lambda\right)^{2}\leq E\left(T-\lambda\right)^{2}$?

I have tried the following,
$$
\begin{align}
E\left(T-\lambda\right)^{2} &= E\left(T-\bar{X}+\bar{X}-\lambda\right)^{2} \\ 
&= E\left(T-\bar{X}\right)^{2} + E\left(\bar{X}-\lambda\right)^{2} + E\left(T-\bar{X}\right)\left(\bar{X}-\lambda\right)
\end{align}
$$
but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your asking "How do we prove without any theorem in Statistics" is a little much.

You should first check that the  expectation of your rival estimator $T$, conditional on $\overline X$, is actually $\overline X$.  Then you appeal to Jensen's inequality.  When you are done you have rediscovered an application of [Rao-Blackwellization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem), a beautiful idea with  an ugly name.